# Why I have component export error on app page

Tags: reactjs, typescript, craco

When I start my project a have error in dev tools console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'default')
    at Module.AddLesson (groupName.tsx:49:1)
    at ./src/pages/changes/components/changeElement/changeElement.tsx (changeElement.tsx:16:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
    at ./src/pages/changes/components/index.ts (groupName.tsx:49:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
    at ./src/pages/changes/changesMain.tsx (methods.ts:24:1)
```

[image: Code from dev tools]

I use craco for aliases

craco config:

```
const path = require('path')
module.exports = {
    webpack: {
        alias: {
            '@components': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components'),
            '@atoms': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/atoms'),
            '@hooks': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/hooks'),
            '@interfaces': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/interfaces'),
            '@pages': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/pages'),
            '@queries': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/queries'),
            '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        },
    },
}
```

In console "No issues found."

Comment: you have export twice.

Comment: @Terchila Marian, I fix it. but error remained